# Date Field Issue in Union query when setting PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When executing a PDO prepared query with emulate_prepares set to false, with a date column and a union statement the date field is returned malformed (eg. expected result: 2019-10-02, actual result: \xe3\x07\n\x02)

Query runs as expected with emulate_prepares set to true.

PHP Version: 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
DB Version: 10.1.41-MariaDB-0ubuintu0.18.04.1

I'm providing a very simple query below to demonstrate the issue but normally this query runs against an actual table with real data. The same issue manifests in both cases.

```php
<?php

$options= [
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_BOUND,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE
];

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbnam=db;charset=utf8', user, password, $options);

$stmt = $db->prepare("
SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS 'date' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL");

$stmt->bindColumn("date", $date);

$stmt->execute();

while($stmt->fetch())
{
print $date."<br>";
}
```

```
Results for PDO:ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = FALSE
�
�

Results for PDO:ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = TRUE
2019-10-02
2019-10-02
```

The date is returned correctly if I remove the Union.

Comment: Can't confirm. Both return dates.  10.3.17-MariaDB-log

Comment: Try calling `$stmt->bindColumn("date", $date);` *after* `$stmt->execute();` and pass `PDO::FETCH_BOUND` to your call to `$stmt->fetch()` if you want to be strictly correct as I read the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Your Common Sense for checking on your end, upgrading resolved the issue. I'm on version 10.4.8-MariaDB now and the issue is resolved.

I ran apt-get to make sure I was on the latest version of MariaDB but forgot to check what version Ubuntu 18.04 limited MaraiDB to on the base repos. I should have applied my own common sense.